# Looping over two R dataframes to create a third dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to backtest a trading strategy.

I am coding in R 3.6

The data is in two dataframes.  The first is five years of daily price activity (i.e. fiveyrdaily).  The second dataframe is price activity for the same five years only at the one minute level (i.e. fiveyrminutes).  This data includes sessions low, high, open, and close.

My strategy is to loop over the respective days of the minute dataframe, while referring to and populating data on the daily dataframe to determine the following:

1. Condition that warrants the opening of a position (i.e. long or short).
2. Whether the target or stop price has been achieved.
3. Log the "trade" on a third dataframe (ORBOorders).

The embedded loops are not working the way I thought they would and I can't figure out why.

I know I can make the code simplier but it keeps getting drawn out so I can figure out where it is I'm going wrong.

I understand that appending to a vector in a loop is not the preferred way to handle vectors but I don't know how large the vector will be after the program is complete.  I'd love to hear any ideas.

This is a strategy that seeks to catch price as it moves out of the range established in the first five minutes of the day.

This is the code to identify the direction of price movement after the initial 5 minutes.  The counter is not working.  The goal is to know the index of a specific event within the subsetted fiveyrminute dataframe (i.e. todaysdate); I will use this in the next batch of code below.  The counter starts at 6 for the sixth minute.  The output is never higher than 7, so, it's not counting with each iteration of the loop.  I can't figure out why.

```r
for (i in 1:length(fiveyrdaily$Date)){
    todaysdate <- subset(fiveyrminutes, fiveyrdaily$Date[i] == fiveyrminutes$Date) # subset so I'm only seeing the respective days in the minutes dataframe
    counter3 <- 6  # start a counter so I can track which position I'm in within the minutes dataframe, start after ORBO
    for (t in counter:length(todaysdate$Date)){  #loop over the minutes dataframe
         if ((fiveyrdaily$FiveHighClose[i] == 0) & (todaysdate$Close[t] > fiveyrdaily$FiveMinuteHigh[i])) {
             fiveyrdaily$FiveHighClose[i] <- todaysdate$Close[t]
             fiveyrdaily$FiveHighAfterClose[i] <- todaysdate$High[t] #record the session's high
             counter3 <- counter3 + 1
             fiveyrdaily$counterhigh[i] <- counter3 # record the position of this event within the subset of the minute dataframe
          }
          else if ((fiveyrdaily$FiveLowClose[i] == 0) & (todaysdate$Close[t] < fiveyrdaily$FiveMinuteLow[i])) {
               fiveyrdaily$FiveLowClose[i] <- todaysdate$Close[t]
               fiveyrdaily$FiveLowAfterClose[i] <- todaysdate$Low[t] # record the session's low
               counter3 <- counter3 + 1
               fiveyrdaily$counterlow[i] <- counter3
          }
          counter3 <- counter + 1
     }
 }
```

This is the "for" loop to determine if to buy and record the outcome.

```r
#Open a long position
for (i in 1:length(fiveyrdaily$Date)){
     if ((fiveyrdaily$counterhigh[i] < fiveyrdaily$counterlow[i]) & openposition < 2) {

          #entryprice is the price predetermined ticks above the high
          entryprice <- fiveyrdaily$FiveHighAfterClose[i] + (openticksaway * tickvalue)
          #create stoploss
          stoplossprice <- entryprice - stoplossvalue
          #uncover target closest to five minute high
          if (possibletargets > fiveyrdaily$FiveHighAfterClose[i]){ fiveyrdaily$ORBOtarget[i] <- min(possibletargets)}

          poscounter <- fiveyrdaily$counterhigh[i]
          beginforloop <- todaysdate[poscounter]

          for (c in beginforloop:length(todaysdate$Date)){ #see where to open position starting from the occurence of the high
               if ((entryprice > todaysdate$Low[c]) & (entryprice < todaysdate$High[c]) & (openposition < 2)){ #determine if conditions warrant entry
                    openposition <- openposition + 1 # open a position
                    if (openposition > 0){ #trade management
                         openpos <- 1
                         if ((stoplossprice < todaysdate$high[c]) & (stoplossprice > todaysdate$Low[c])){ # determine if stoploss has been hit
                              orderdate <- c(orderdate, todaysdate[c]) #enter data into orders dataframe
                              orderstrategy <- c(orderstrategy, "ORBO")
                              ordertype <- c(ordertype, "Long")
                              ordersymbol <- c(ordersymbol, "ES")
                              orderentry <- c(orderentry, entryprice)
                              orderclose <- c(orderclose, stoplossprice)
                              orderprofit <- c(orderprofit, abs((entryprice - stoplossprice) * pointvalue))
                              openpos <- 0
                         }
                         else if ((fiveyrdaily$ORBOtarget[i] < todaysdate$high[c]) & (fiveyrdaily$ORBOtarget[i] > todaysdate$Low[c])){ # determine if target has been hit
                              orderdate <- c(orderdate, todaysdate[c]) #enter data into orders dataframe
                              orderstrategy <- c(orderstrategy, "ORBO")
                              ordertype <- c(ordertype, "Long")
                              ordersymbol <- c(ordersymbol, "ES")
                              orderentry <- c(orderentry, entryprice)
                              orderclose <- c(orderclose, stoplossprice)
                              orderprofit <- c(orderprofit, abs((fiveyrdaily$ORBOtarget[i] - entryprice) * pointvalue))
                              openpos <- 0
                         }
                    }
               }
          }
    }
}
```

Here is the data that is in the daily dataframe - fiveyrdaily:

```r
> tail(fiveyrdaily)
           Date  Time    Open    High     Low   Close     Vol      OI UpperBand
1254 06/12/2019 16:15 2883.50 2889.75 2875.25 2881.00 1205406 2495060   2919.12
1255 06/13/2019 16:15 2894.75 2900.50 2886.75 2898.50  523312  448119   2925.39
1256 06/14/2019 16:15 2893.00 2899.75 2884.25 2894.75 1318938  951568   2927.99
1257 06/17/2019 16:15 2895.50 2902.75 2892.00 2896.25 1649621 1595842   2932.71
1258 06/18/2019 16:15 2914.00 2936.50 2910.25 2926.25 2257843 2093571   2944.19
1259 06/19/2019 16:15 2925.50 2936.75 2915.25 2933.50 1639495 2093571   2954.61
     LowerBand MidLine      PP   RSI OverBot OverSld SlowK SlowD OverBot.1
1254   2751.13 2835.13 2892.58 56.24      70      30 86.82 87.54        80
1255   2749.21 2837.30 2882.00 59.06      70      30 87.60 88.11        80
1256   2748.24 2838.11 2895.25 58.19      70      30 89.01 87.81        80
1257   2746.94 2839.82 2892.92 58.46      70      30 91.79 89.47        80
1258   2743.68 2843.94 2897.00 63.41      70      30 92.63 91.14        80
1259   2740.02 2847.31 2924.33 64.51      70      30 95.20 93.21        80
     OverSld.1  Volume Momentum ZeroLine   InOrOut GapUpOrDown TypeOfDay PPTrend
1254        20 1205406    49.25        0 Disregard   Disregard      Bear Uptrend
1255        20  523312    93.50        0 Disregard      Gap Up      Bull Uptrend
1256        20 1318938   114.75        0 Disregard   Disregard      Bull Uptrend
1257        20 1649621   105.75        0 Disregard   Disregard      Bull Uptrend
1258        20 2257843   173.75        0 Disregard      Gap Up      Bull Uptrend
1259        20 1639495   184.00        0 Disregard   Disregard      Bull Uptrend
     FiveMinuteLow FiveMinuteHigh FiveMinHtoL DollarFiveHtoL FiveHighClose
1254       2881.25        2889.75        8.50          425.0          0.00
1255       2892.00        2895.75        3.75          187.5       2896.00
1256       2886.25        2893.75        7.50          375.0       2894.75
1257       2892.00        2897.00        5.00          250.0       2897.25
1258       2910.25        2915.50        5.25          262.5       2920.75
1259       2923.25        2927.25        4.00          200.0       2930.00
     FiveHighAfterClose FiveLowClose FiveLowAfterClose ORBOtarget counterhigh
1254               0.00      2881.00           2880.75          0           0
1255            2896.00      2891.75           2891.00          0           6
1256            2894.75      2886.00           2885.00          0           7
1257            2897.50         0.00              0.00          0           7
1258            2921.75         0.00              0.00          0           7
1259            2931.50      2922.50           2922.25          0           7
     counterlow DollarOpentoHigh DollarOpentoClose DollarOpentoLow
1254          7            312.5             125.0           412.5
1255          7            287.5             187.5           400.0
1256          7            337.5              87.5           437.5
1257          0            362.5              37.5           175.0
1258          0           1125.0             612.5           187.5
1259          7            562.5             400.0           512.5
```

This is the data that is in the minutes dataframe - fiveyrminutes:

```r
Date  Time    Open    High     Low   Close   Up Down UpperBand
509796 06/19/2019 16:10 2932.25 2932.50 2932.25 2932.50  717  430   2935.66
509797 06/19/2019 16:11 2932.25 2932.50 2932.25 2932.25  125  276   2935.46
509798 06/19/2019 16:12 2932.25 2932.75 2932.25 2932.75  612  604   2934.95
509799 06/19/2019 16:13 2932.50 2933.25 2932.50 2933.00  830  153   2934.66
509800 06/19/2019 16:14 2933.25 2933.25 2932.75 2933.00  676  376   2934.26
509801 06/19/2019 16:15 2932.75 2934.00 2932.75 2933.25 2929 2026   2933.90
       LowerBand MidLine      PP   RSI OverBot OverSld SlowK SlowD OverBot.1
509796   2930.27 2932.96 2932.42 47.94      70      30 45.45 40.66        80
509797   2930.24 2932.85 2932.42 46.22      70      30 53.70 46.21        80
509798   2930.45 2932.70 2932.33 50.07      70      30 63.83 54.33        80
509799   2930.56 2932.61 2932.58 51.92      70      30 72.73 63.42        80
509800   2930.76 2932.51 2932.92 51.92      70      30 83.33 73.30        80
509801   2930.97 2932.44 2933.00 53.90      70      30 85.00 80.35        80
       OverSld.1 Volume Momentum ZeroLine
509796        20   1147    -0.50        0
509797        20    401    -1.00        0
509798        20   1216     1.75        0
509799        20    983     1.75        0
509800        20   1052     2.00        0
509801        20   4955     1.75        0
```

This is the output for the orders dataframe, notice how it's empty - ORBOorders:

```r
ORBOorders
  orderdate orderstrategy ordertype ordersymbol orderentry orderclose
1                                                        0          0
  orderprofit
1           0
```

These are the problems:

-counter3 isn't working (to find after which point I should buy)

-The second batch of code gives this error:

> Error in beginforloop:length(todaysdate$Date) : argument of length 0
>   In addition: Warning message: In if (possibletargets >
>   fiveyrdaily$FiveHighAfterClose[i]) { :   the condition has length > 1
>   and only the first element will be used

-The ORBOorder dataframe has absolutely no data in it.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sounds like an interesting question which might be solved using R's vector functions and/or merge/join operations rather than looping. Please, provide a [mcve] including sample datasets and the expected result. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm happy to finally ask questions.  This is a great site and I've used it for so long!  I didn't know about the merge/join operations and will look into it.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. However, please [edit] your question and provide sample data. This might help other SO users who might have related problems.

Comment: I updated the question like you recommended.  The sample data and code is now included with the question.